# The requested resource / was not found on this server. Laravel on Cloud9 IDE

Tags: php, laravel, cloud9-ide

hey guys i was following the laravel installation guide for cloud9 IDE [here](https://docs.c9.io/docs/laravel)
and when go run the app i get following in the screen shot below [image]

im still new so my debugging solutions are very limited, does anyone know whats wrong on cloud9 ide?

Comment: I had the same issue on Yii2 in c9, when i ran server via 'php -S 0.0.0.0:8081' NOT in 'web' directory, but in the root folder. May be this helps.

Comment: @gorvic i actaully forgot to change directorys during the installation.... but everything went according to the documentation provided by c9.io

Answer (score 4):

Under the tab called 'PHP - Running' which opens when you click the 'Run Project' button, click on where it says 'Runner: ' (between the green bug icon and 'CWD') and select 'Appache httpd (PHP, HTML)'

After changing that setting I had to log out and back in again to get the project to run, but the problem appeared to be fixed.

Comment: ive tried the following command `php -S ip_address:port_number -t public` and that still doesnt work. It just gives me a redirect to a yahoo DNS page. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: @Sambhav did this work for u? And if so how did u get it to work?

Comment: @Hello world
Did you try the steps mentioned by Wkille ? 
Did you select 'Appache httpd (PHP, HTML)'
After selecting Apache httpd (PHP, HTML) you need to logout and then login.

Comment: @hello world..Hmm in that case Sorry I don't have any answers because I followed exactly the same steps given by "Wkille" and it worked fine for me.

Comment: I didn't have to log out and back in, but I did need to stop project and run project again after changing to 'Appache httpd (PHP, HTML)'

Answer (score 4):

I was facing same issue while running ZF application.
Actually I was executing following command

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t /d/MyProjectRootFolder/
```

Actually I forgot to add public folder path as

```
php -S 127.0.0.1:80 -t /d/MyProjectRootFolder/public/
```

This fixed issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.

In my case, I added next line in *routes.php*
**Route::resource('image','ImageController');**

But, in **/public** directory, it was **/public/image** directory.

Solution:

change directory's name for: **/public/img**

or change *routes.php*: **Route::resource('imageSite','ImageController');**

Regards!

Answer (score -1):

The name (path) is the same as the file name in (general) you must change the file name