# Laravel 5.6 - The requested resource /home was not found on this server

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am having a bit of an issue with one route (and only with this one, every other route works without any issue).

This are my routes (I commented out all routes, except the /home, just to be sure that they are not messing up something):

```
<?php

// Route::get('/', 'DashboardController@index')->middleware('menu.admin')->name('home');
Route::get('/home', 'DashboardController@index')->middleware('menu.admin')->name('home');

// Route::get('/user/verify/{token}', 'Auth\RegisterController@verifyUser');

// Route::get('logout', '\App\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@logout');

// Auth::routes();

// // Admin routes (admin dashboard)
// require(base_path() . '/routes/admin.php');

// // Site routes (frontend)
// require(base_path() . '/routes/front.php');
```

I am getting this error:

```
Not Found
The requested resource /home was not found on this server.
```

The **/** route works without any issues, and when I try **/home** (the only difference between this two routes), I am getting the error.

I did **php artisan route:clear**, and it didn't help. Does anyone have an idea what is going on (**.htaccess** file is not an issue here)?

Comment: I don't think you intend to specify the path `/home` .  That will be the directory containing all user account directories.  Home is more usually found at `/var/www/html` for web services.

Comment: **Follow this answer, I hope it’s working** https://stackoverflow.com/a/47164626/10152403

Answer (score 13):

## Laravel ^5.6

if your routes are defined properly, and by properly i mean you defineded routes in the right order (to avoid conflicts) and the artisan command <kbd>php artisan route:list</kbd> get executed correctly BUT you still get **404 Not found - The requested resource /path was not found on this server.** weird, not exactly what you were expecting!!

...i also faced this problem, and here is the thing, that error occurs *when* you create a **folder** in the **public** directory *with* the same **URI**

...to illustrate here's an example (this is the problem i faced)

---

#### routes/web.php

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes - Backend
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

Route::group(['namespace' => 'Backend', 'prefix' => 'backend'], function () {

    Route::get('/', 'DashboardController')->name('backend.dashboard');

    // ...
});
```

---

#### php artisan route:list

<kbd>php artisan route:list --name=backend --columns=uri --columns=name</kbd>

```
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| URI                            | Name                                 |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
| backend                        | backend.dashboard                    |
| // ...                         | // ...                               |
+--------------------------------+--------------------------------------+
```

---

#### public/

```
+---public
|   +---backend
|   |   +---css
|   |   +---fonts
|   |   +---images
|   |   +---js
|   +---.htaccess
|   +---favicon.ico
|   +---index.php
|   +---mix-manifest.json
|   +---robots.txt
```

---

As you can see, i have a route *URI* that start with **backend** AND also a folder under the public directory named **backend** as well, that's what cause the problem, so it's up to you to change one of those, personally i changed the name of the folder under public directory to "*back-end*". that solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. The folder name conflict with the route was really bugging me. Your post here immediately corrected the issue! Much appreciated.

Comment: PERFECT thank you. I had a directory named 'forms' and a page slug named 'forms' as well. just changed the page name to 'formspage' and all quiet on the western front!

Comment: That solved the issue for me as well. I had created a directory called listings in the public directory, and that was causing issues.

Answer (score 1):

Because, you have a folder named control on /public folder. That error occurs when you create a folder in the public folder with the same name as your route so please change the name of the folder you have put in the public folder so that it has a different name from your route this will probably solve your error

Comment: Spot on! Quite difficult finding this answer with Google too.

Answer (score 0):

you use apache or nginx as web server?

try to set config for webserver
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/installation